# Moving wireless client from one to another access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking

Since Access Point of my primary router (D-Link DSR250N) does not cover the whole appartment, I have bought secondary router (PixLink) to be an additional Access Point, and bound them together LAN to LAN.  The physical set-up can be seen on the picture:

[image]

The software set-up:

- both routers with 20MHz bandwidth
- primary router channel 6, secondary router channel 11
- DHCP server off on secondary router
- all devices have MAC addresses bound to unique IP addresses.

The set-up is generally working fine, but there is one important issue.  If I move my wireless client from Area B to Area A, the Internet connection works seamlessly.  However if I move my wireless device from Area A to Area B, Internet stops working for that device for exactly 10 minutes.  That is, device is immediatelly connected to PixLink router and also gets the proper IP address, but Internet is inactive.

Could you please tell me what is wrong?  Is the problem in the primary (D-Link) or secondary (PixLink) router?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Roaming is decided by the client. Does the same thing happen when you use a different wireless client?

Comment: @JohnStoneman I know that all clients have the problem, but I have researched the problem extensivelly only with one wireless client.  I shall do these tests now.  However, what is striking is that the problem is assymetric.  Why would wireless client prefer one access point to another?

Comment: I just realised that very similar question also appeared on D-Link forums, but the problem was never resolved: http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=62199.0

Comment: @JohnStoneman I have tested three different wireless clients.  The problem is exactly the same.